# Implementing Input Splits(HADOOP)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Talking about **Big Data** , say we have a very large file(in GB's) say, and we know **HDFS** stores files in a distributed manner that is in blocks, considering a block size of say **128 MB** , is there a possibility that certain blocks would be like this :

**Block 1** :

**_______________**

This is line one.

This is line two.

This is line three.

This is line four.

This is line

**Block 2** :

**_________________**

five.

This is line six.

This is line seven.

This is line eight.

This is line nine.

This is line ten.

I know the concept of **Input Splits** and how its a logical boundary rather than a physical one but I have never seen it's implementation. Sure I have read articles describing which methods should be overridden etc etc.. But my first doubt remains is this division really possible like half a record here and half there ?

If yes any ideas on its implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nice explanation about this here.

```
https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/
```

And also here

```
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LineRecordReader.java#L243
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This situation is possible when the block size is reached and it creates the next block.
**You can simulate this situation by setting the block size with 4 kb and put your content and move it to DFS. There you can see the last line splits between two blocks.** 
And this itself is a good example of input splits. When the process happens, the control will access the block 2 also to get the pending data of the unfinished line in block 1. When the last record in a block is incomplete, the input split includes location information for the next block and the byte offset of the data needed to complete the record.

Comment: Actually I did try to simulate that situation , I set the block size to be as 4kb and uploaded a file of size 4.7kb. I just created a map-reduce code with no reducers just a mapper which throws the offset key and the value of the record. Now the job counters displayed the input splits as 2 but the mapper output came out to be a single file contradicting the number of input splits. Is that possible these kind of situations are handled by the framework automatically ? (Hadoop v2.7.1)